# When to purchase tickets between NZ islands

Tags: tickets, new-zealand

I am planning a trip to visit both New Zealand islands over a few weeks in January. The plan is to start on South Island and then make our way to North Island. We haven't decided whether we want to fly or take a ferry between islands, though we would make that decision before leaving on the trip. The start and end dates for the trip are fixed, but not what we do once we're in NZ.

We were hoping to leave some of our sightseeing on the islands fairly flexible, in case we decide we want to see more and take an extra day or two on one of the islands. How far in advance is it recommended to purchase tickets to travel between the islands? Is it practical to wait to purchase ferry or flight tickets until we've started our trip and book with only a few days' notice, or do we really need to book well in advance?

Comment: As a NZer, I recommend the ferry rather than flying as it's quite beautiful scenery on the trip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:** January is the busiest time for travel between the North and South Islands.But, if you are planning to cross mid/late January without a vehicle you should be fine to wait until you are in the country.

**Full answer:** 
January is probably the busiest time for travel between the North and South Islands. However, the difficulty in booking depends entirely on when you might be aiming to cross. If you are flexible and planning to cross mid/late January you should be fine to delay until you know your plann. Here are some things to think about...

First - will be you be travelling with a car / camper? If so, try to arrange to drop it off when you cross and pick up another on the other island. The ferry is far more expensive with a car / van, and you are more likely to need to book in advance.

Second - the busiest time over summer is Christmas to New Years and then the few days in early Jan before everyone goes back to work. Judging by public holidays, many people will return to work on the Mon 7th next year (2019), so expect it to be busy before that. It will quieten down after that but weekends may still be busy. Travelling mid week should be fine to book on a few days in advance.

Also, most schools will start the year from the 28th to the 7th Feb so there will be another busier period then.

Third - your options to travel. There are 2 ferries that cross between Picton and Wellington:

- [Bluebridge](http://www.bluebridge.co.nz/)
- [Interislander](https://www.greatjourneysofnz.co.nz/interislander)

There are also flights between Wellington and Blenheim, Picton, Or Nelson through [Sounds Air](https://www.soundsair.com/). Plus Air New Zealand and Jetstar between the bigger cities. So you have plenty of options when it comes to travel and should be able to get something at shortish notice.

Sounds air and the ferries are both great trips on a good day.